How to lookup from BTreeMap with a two-tuple as key, using the first element?
I have a BTreeMap where I store items using a two-tuple key, (String, i32), so the type of map that stores integers is BTreeMap<(String, i32), i32>.
Is there a way I can lookup elements by using the first element of the two-tuple? E.g. some form of custom range? How would I do that?
A short example:
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m : BTreeMap<(String, i32), i32> = BTreeMap::new();
    m.insert(("hello".to_string(), 12), 34);
    m.insert(("hello".to_string(), 4), 56);
    m.insert(("other".to_string(), 4), 44);

    let one_element = m.get(&("hello".to_string(), 12));
    println!("{:?}", one_element);

    // does not work, perhaps some custom range could be used?
    let all_hello = m.get(&("hello".to_string(), _));
}


You can use BTreeMap::range to do this:
let range = m.range(("hello".to_string(), i32::MIN)..=("hello".to_string(), i32::MAX));

for item in range {
    println!("{:?}", item);
}

(Playground)
Note that because of the way the Borrow trait works, you unfortunately have to allocate two strings, one for each end of the range.

Nice trick to use i32::MIN and i32::MAX. Is there any corresponding trick for Vec<i32> or Vec<_>, so that the second element in the two-tuple could be any Vector ? Alternatively a slice?

No, in that case the simplest would probably be to use a half-open range, and the next value up for the first part of the key e.g. "g".to_string() (and you can use an empty vec as the second part, doesn't matter). Alternatively — and that's pretty common too — just don't set an upper bound to the range and stop dynamically e.g. using a take_while iterator adapter.

@Masklinn I created another question for Vector / slice ranges https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78583177/how-to-lookup-ranges-from-btreemap-using-slice-patterns-or-vectors
