How to lookup ranges from BTreeMap using slice patterns or vectors?
I have a BTreeMap where I store items using a two-tuple key, (String, Vec<i32>), so the type of map that stores integers is BTreeMap<(String, Vec<i32>), i32>.
How can I get ranges by using the first element in the two-tuple while ignoring the content of the Vector (alternatively a slice &[i32])?
A short example:
//use core::slice::SlicePattern;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m : BTreeMap<(String, Vec<i32>), i32> = BTreeMap::new();
    m.insert(("hello".to_string(), vec![12]), 34);
    m.insert(("hello".to_string(), vec![4]), 56);
    m.insert(("other".to_string(), vec![4]), 44);

    let res_first = m.get(&("hello".to_string(), vec![12]));
    println!("{:?}", res_first);

    // not working, and not intuitive range
    for (k, v) in m.range(("hello".to_string(), [])..=("g".to_string(), [])) {
        println!("key {:?}", k);
    }
}

Is there a way I can use a slice pattern or something to make the range query work with Vectors or slices?
or something like:
m.range(("hello".to_string(), [])..=("hello".to_string(), [RangeFull]))

My previous question got a good answer, but it only works for scalars and not Vector or slices.

vec![] is the lower bound for vecs, but there is no upper bound, so the trick doesn't work here. You can wrap it in a type like struct WithMax<T>{ Val(T), Max } and define an appropriate Ord implementation which compares Max as greater than any Val, which would give you the property you expect from [RangeFull].

@user2407038 Unfortunately the bound of BTreeMap::range doesn't allow you to specify a different type that implements PartialOrd<K>, because that would definitely be the ideal way to solve this.

You can do this much the same way, except that you need a range where the end is exclusive, since you can't (easily) express the maximum possible Vec<i32>.  You can specify an empty Vec for both ends of the range, and use the next-"largest" string at the end of the range, which is just the same string with a nul character added. (Thanks Filipe for this idea.)
m.range(("hello".to_string(), vec![])..("hello\0".to_string(), vec![]))

(Playground)

It doesn't actually work: it won't select if the vec has length > 1 and starts with i32::MAX e.g. vec![i32::MAX, i32::MIN]. You'd need vec![i32::MAX;usize::MAX], to ensure total correctness with this scheme, and that's not realistic.

@Masklinn Hmm, I see. That's unfortunate. It would be nice if you could supply any range of T where T: PartialOrd<K> to BTreeMap::range because then you could write a newtype that would handle this nicely.

@Masklinn Fixed using a different approach (range + take_while).

One disadvantage is this makes the iterator not implement DoubleEndedIterator. It might not matter for OP, but it's something to keep in mind, since the iterator returned by range is DoubleEndedIterator.

@FilipeRodrigues Yep, there isn't a good way I can find to make that work. BTreeMap would need to be changed in some way to allow you to use your own PartialOrd<K>-implementing type as the range bounds.

Hm, maybe you could do something like range(("hello".to_string(), vec![])..("hellp".to_string(), vec![])) (notice the hellp on the upper bound). Lexicographically, hellp should be the next string right after hello, if I'm not mistaken, so this could work?

Nevermind, that won't work, the next string lexicographically after hello is hello\0\0\0\0... with infinite \0s.

@FilipeRodrigues Wait, is it really the one with infinite nuls, or would it just be hello\0?

@cdhowie You're right, I just tested it on the playground, it is just hello\0, so that could work.

@FilipeRodrigues Yeah that's actually quite a clever solution. We could generalize the solution for a tuple (T, ...) where T: Step and the rest of the types implement Default, if Step were stable, and if String: Step. Interestingly, the Step::forward implementation for String is actually pretty simple (add count nuls) but the Step::backward implementation is where we get into infinite-length string territory.

@FilipeRodrigues Updated my answer to use this technique.

@FilipeRodrigues Retracting the bit about Default. We'd need another trait for the minimum value of a type, since e.g. i32::default() is not the minimum value. But I digress.
